# How to read console from WebBrowser in .NET

Tags: c#, javascript, json, vb.net, web

Now I will make an API with javascript, I will open the javascript from web browser tool in .NET application but I cannot read the result of my API. When I open from Firefox browser i can read console result with add on "Firebug" like this :

[image]

my problem is: how to read result console in .NET if i open the HTML contains API script with webpage navigate in VB.NET?

This is the HTML links that's contain my API : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91736888/s/createpaste.html

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question: Do you want to read the JS Console on the client side and submit it to the server?

Comment: sorry i am newbie and i cant english more... yes i will generate my api from VB.NET..

Comment: Sorry, still does not clarify the question to me - maybe try to explain it in some more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: i will make a pastes in binbox(like pastebin)but i'll use VB.NET to genrate a lot of pastes https://binbox.io/api. 
in binbox.io provide make a paste with api. there are javascript api and i cant use it in VB.NET to make pastes, i only can use their API from(javascript)with open the HTML that contains API script on firefox and read the result with Firebug.
my problem is i cannt use Binbox API in VB.NET and i have idea with open HTML file that contains javascript API to generate pastes from vb.net so i can make a lot of pastes from VB.Net but i cant read console result like firebug in VB - web